# Compare nums need optimisation (codingame.com)

Tags: python

```
www.codingame.com
```

**Task**

```
Write a program which, using a given number of strengths, 
identifies the two closest strengths and shows their difference with an integer
```

**Info**

```
n = Number of horses
pi = strength of each horse
d = difference

1 < n  < 100000
0 < pi ≤ 10000000
```

**My code currently**

```
def get_dif(a, b):
    return abs(a - b)

horse_str = [10, 5, 15, 17, 3, 8, 11, 28, 6, 55, 7]
n = len(horse_str)
d = 10000001

for x in range(len(horse_str)):
    for y in range(x, len(horse_str) - 1):
        d = min([get_dif(horse_str[x], horse_str[y + 1]), d])

print(d)
```

**Test cases**

```
[3,5,8, 9] outputs: 1
[10, 5, 15, 17, 3, 8, 11, 28, 6, 55, 7] outputs: 1
```

**Problem**

They both work but then the next test gives me a very long list of horse strengths and i get **`Process has timed out. This may mean that your solution is not optimized enough to handle some cases.`

How can i optimise it? Thank you!

**EDIT ONE**

**Default code given**

```
import sys
import math

# Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
# the standard input according to the problem statement.

n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    pi = int(input())

# Write an action using print
# To debug: print("Debug messages...", file=sys.stderr)

print("answer")
```

Comment: First, that's not bubblesort. Second, why would you use bubblesort?

Comment: are you allowed to use python built-in `sort` ?

Comment: @user2357112 Helpful comments would be nice

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can use `sort` method (which is optimized to avoid performing a costly bubble sort or double loop by hand which has `O(n**2)` complexity, and times out with a very big list), let me propose something:

- sort the list
- compute the minimum of absolute value of difference of the adjacent values, passing a generator comprehension to the `min` function

The minimum has to be the abs difference of adjacent values. Since the list is sorted using a fast algorithm, the heavy lifting is done for you.

like this:

```
horse_str = [10, 5, 15, 17, 3, 8, 11, 28, 6, 55, 7]

sh = sorted(horse_str)
print(min(abs(sh[i]-sh[i+1]) for i in range(len(sh)-1)))
```

I also get `1` as a result (I hope I didn't miss anything)

Comment: Oh off course! not sure why i didn't think about sorting it to start with aha!

Comment: I'll let you submit this to your online engine and accept the answer if it works.